# Howto dynamically localize the full URL (including Controller, Action and other parameters) in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am looking for a solution to dynamic configure the routing in ASP.NET MVC 3, based on the current language the user is using on the website.

now i have:

```
domain.com/de/controller/action/subaction/XX
domain.com/en/controller/action/subaction/XX
```

and i would like to have:

```
domain.com/de/bereich/aktion/unteraktion/XX
domain.com/en/controller/action/subaction/XX
```

the name for the controller/action & subaction should be configurable through the Database (the german names as well as the english ones)

As the default route configuration works well in ASP.NET MVC, i would prefer to use it, and e.g. just customize the class that handles the mapping between the URL and the controller (etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-%28ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms%29.aspx this article will help you exactly with your problem but please think about it twice.

Comment: Thanks! this is even better than i need it ;) - with this solution i can get rid of the disturbing language prefix (`/de/` & `/en/`) in the path

Comment: QQping why do you warn us to use that ?

Comment: Is it even necessary? What happens when the user has german as his default language and visits an english translated url from this website? Just a few questions that should come to mind when you are talking about localization of paths... IMHO it is overkill.